# Understanding the morphisms for an $H$-cogroup

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm reviewing my notes for an Algebraic topology course and am having trouble with the notion of an $H$-cogroup.

I know that an $H$-group $X$ should have morphisms 
$$\mu:X\times X\to X$$ 
$$i:X\to X$$
$$e:X\to X$$
such that certain diagrams commute, and I understand the logic of these diagrams. (Correspond, in a sense to associativity, existence of inverses, and existence of identity element.)

I also understand that an $H$-cogroup $Y$ should come equipped with morphisms that satisfy 'dual' axioms, say
$$\nu:Y\to Y\vee Y$$
$$i:Y\to Y$$
$$e:Y\to Y.$$

The dual to the associativity diagram is clear to me. My issue is with understanding the duals to the other two diagrams: sources I have looked at say (taking the identity diagram for example) that we should have the composite
$$(1\vee e)\circ\nu=id_Y,$$
up to homotopy.

But I can't figure out how to view $(1\vee e)$ as a map $Y\vee Y\to Y.$ Am I missing something obvious here, or is there another way to denote this map that would potentially make it more clear?

Thanks you!

Comment: It is the unique map induced by the identity $\mathbb 1_Y$ on $Y$ on the first "summand" and by the map $e:Y\to Y$ on the other. $Y\vee Y$ is the coproduct, so giving two maps with domain $Y$ determines another map with domain $Y\vee Y$. For pointed spaces and pointed maps it would be the wedge sum for example.

Comment: Thank you, but I think I am still missing something. The map you are describing sounds like a map $K\vee K\to K\vee K$ and based on my notes and book, the codomain should be just $K$.

Comment: The map has codomain $K$. Consider for example the case $K=S^1$. We have an identity $\mathbb 1_S$ on $S^1$, and we have the map $e:S^1\to\{s_0\}$, where $s_0$ is the basepoint of the circle. Then $(\mathbb 1_S\vee e):S^1\vee S^1\to S^1$ is the map sending a point $s$ from the first circle to the point $s$, and each point from the second circle to $s_0$. Since the circles are wedged as their respective $s_0$'s which are both sent to $s_0$, this is well-defined.

Comment: If $\nu:S^1\to S^1\vee S^1$ is the map which wraps the circle first around the first circle and then around the second circle, then $(1\vee e)\circ\nu$ will be the map which goes around the circle on the first $180°$ (with double speed), and then stays fixed at $s_0$ on the remaining $180°$. This is a map homotopic to the identity on $S^1$.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you so much!